# Previous and Next keyboard buttons using UITextfields on Static UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` with static cells to show a form with several `UITextFields` (each with a unique ordered tag from 9000 to 9015).
When i select a `UITextField`, the keyboard shows up with a `UIToolbar` that has 2 buttons, previous and next. The buttons work fine as long as the previous or next `UITextField` is drawn on screen, otherwise i can not select it because `viewWithTag` can't find the Field.

DEMO: http://s15.postimg.org/5xjsoiupl/ezgif_com_video_to_gif.gif

EDIT: I tryed using `IQKeyboardManager`but it has the same bug. If the cells are not visible then they are not detected so the next or previous arrow is disabled...

**UITextFields**

```
let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
numberToolbar.tintColor = color_green

prev_keyboard_button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Previous", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "keyboardPrevButtonTapped:")
next_keyboard_button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "keyboardNextButtonTapped:")

numberToolbar.items = [
    prev_keyboard_button,
    next_keyboard_button,
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "OK", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "keyboardOKButtonTapped:")]

    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
// bind vars
var_input_name.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
var_input_name.delegate = self
var_input_name.tag = 9000  // 9000 + index (0,1,2,3,..)
...
```

Previous and next code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    // current tag
    current_input_tag = textField.tag

    // check if it is the first
    prev_keyboard_button.enabled = !(textField.tag == 9000)

    // check if it is the last
    next_keyboard_button.enabled = !(textField.tag == 9015)

}

func keyboardPrevButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if current_input_tag > 9000 {
        // find next input
        if let input = self.view.viewWithTag(current_input_tag - 1) as? UITextField {
            input.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}

func keyboardNextButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if current_input_tag < 9015 {
        // find next input
        if let input = self.view.viewWithTag(current_input_tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            input.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to always draw the static cells or should i be implementing this differently?

Answer (score 0):

if the sell is out of the screen it will be released. It's no matter if you use static or dynamic cells. Probably views you try to find is not exists at this moment